# SOQL Relationship Problem

Tags: soql

I am getting this error when I try to run this query. I am drawing a blank on why this is happening. Everything else is running correctly. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

> COUNT(Allergies_Types__c) childDairy FROM Child_Consent_Form__c 
>                                             ^ ERROR at Row:9:Column:75 Didn't understand relationship 'Child_Consent_Form__c' in FROM part of
>   query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be
>   sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please
>   reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

```
             SELECT 
                    puLocation__r.Name LocationName, 
                    puLocation__r.notes__c LocationNotes,
                    puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c MilkLocation,
                    puLocation__r.Location_type__c LocationType,
                    Child_Consent_Form__c.Active_Inactive__c,
                    count(ID) numberofchildren,
                    count(Allergies__c) childrenwithalergies,
                    (SELECT COUNT(Allergies_Types__c) childDairy FROM Child_Consent_Form__c 
                       WHERE Allergies_Types__c INCLUDES ('Dairy-free'))
             FROM Child_Consent_Form__c 
             WHERE     Child_Consent_Form__c.Active_Inactive__c = 'Active'
             GROUP BY puLocation__r.Name, 
                      puLocation__r.notes__c,
                      puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c,
                      puLocation__r.Location_type__c,
                      Child_Consent_Form__c.Active_Inactive__c
```

Comment: Have you tried to read error message and apply hint mentioned there?

Comment: Hi @Kurunve! Thank you for the quick response.  Yes I did try that but am still getting the error.  Allergies_Types__c is part of the Child_Consent_Form__c table.  Above the sub-select I am able to get the count of Allergies__c which is also Allergies_Types.

Comment: Move the sub-query to a separate query. Because both the queries are on the same object.

Comment: I really think this approach is misguided. If you would share more details on your data model and overall objective, we might be able to recommend a solution involving some combination of SOQL parent-child queries, rollup summary fields, DLRS, Apex, and/or wrapper objects.

Comment: Hi David. My last goal is to find out how many kids have dairy allergies. Currently, that is a pick list (Allergies_Types__c) under Child_Consent_Form__c. Do you have any idea of a better approach?

Comment: (1) what is the name of your location object? (2) what is the relationship between the two objects (master-detail or lookup)? (3) why are you grouping on so many fields? (4) do you need data points at the location level about child records beyond total count, count with allergies, and count with dairy allergies?

Comment: I have two objects Child_Consent_Form__c and Food_Locations__c.  Child_Consent_Form__c.puLocation__c is the master-detail linked to Food_Locations__c.  I need to know how many active kids per location, how many have allergies (Child_Consent_Form__c.Allergies__c) and how many have dairy-allergies (Child_Consent_Form__c.Allergies_Types__c).

Comment: Have you looked into creating rollup summary fields on the Food_Locations__c object to summarize the totals you need? Then you could query on Food_Locations__c directly, which should simplify your query and also improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your last comment and wanted to modify my answer somewhat.
You can't do what you're doing in that way, you'll either need separate queries, or store the allergies they all have in another object per allergy per child, and then connect them via a lookup to the child form object.

Unlike SQL, everything in SOQL works in relations - if you try and retrieve records from an object, all the subqueries need to be within the context of each record.

This will return how many allergies in total each child has, if you want to filter by a specific type, you'll need to do separate queries after all, as the total allergies of all children have nothing to do with a specific consent form record:

Child_Allergies__c

- Id
- Form_Id__c -> Lookup to Child Form (Child_Form_Allergies__r)

Child_Consent_Form__c

- Id
- Child_Name__c

  SELECT Child_Name__c, (SELECT Count(Id) FROM Child_Form_Allergies__r) total_allergies
  FROM Child_Consent_Form__c

---

This is an explanation on how to use relations in general in SOQL:
[User Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm)

If you read the last quote, you can see:

```
SELECT Name,
  (
    SELECT LastName
    FROM Contacts
    WHERE CreatedBy.Alias = 'x')
FROM Account WHERE Industry = 'media'
```

> This query returns the name for all accounts whose industry is media,
>   and for each account returned, returns the last name of every contact
>   whose created-by alias is 'x.'

In general you should check the name of the relation, because the sub query needs to be related to the record you're retrieving via a relation.

For example:

This works:

```
select id, (select id from tasks where priority = 'abc')
from case
```

While this doesn't:

```
select id, (select id from task where priority = 'abc')
from case
```

(bold not working for me, but in the first example there's an 's' at the end of "task", because the object name may be "task", but the relation name is "tasks".

Comment: Thank you. This is making sense. Moving from SQL to SOQL isn't easy! ;) It sounds like my best bet is to make another query but that leads to the issue that I had when I started this. How do I call another SOQL query from my apx page? How do I pass location name to the query?

My thoughts are to make another public list but I am not sure how to pass that variable to the procedure?  Or do I declare the new public list and build it, along with the alt query for dairy-allergies?


Maybe you can point me in the right direction or give me the keywords to search on?

Comment: I'm not familiar with apex pages that much unfortunately (mostly used lightning), but why not call an apex method which in turn will handle all the logic and just return the data you need?

Comment: @Poster That is bad advice. You *want* to only group related records. `Name` is not a unique field.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sorry, I'm either missing something or it's too early in the morning - where am I suggesting to group by Name? in the model i've shown he's clearly supposed to group by the relations connected between the ids.
in fact, there's no actual 'group by' clause anywhere since it does it on its own via the relation.